# Competitive programming question related to boolean matrix asked in Cohesity's shortlisting test

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, dynamic-programming

A  0-1 matrix of width w and height h was given. 0 means black and 1 means white. Picture it like a bar code. If the whole column is filled with 1s then it’s a white strip on a bar code. if n consecutive columns are filled with 0, then it will represent a black strip of width n. Now the matrix is not perfect(some columns are not completely white or completely black i.e. they have some irregularities).

Cost of switching a single 0 with 1 and vice versa is 1.

You are given x and y where x is the minimum width a strip in the barcode must have and y is the max width. You have to find the minimum cost required to convert the original imperfect matrix into a valid barcode matrix satisfying constraints on x and y i.e. each strip’s width is between [x,y].

Brute force backtracking does not work, getting TLE.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Please share your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a column as possibly being one of (1) `b`, a rightmost black column in a black strip, and (2) `w`, a rightmost white column in a white strip. Let `C` be a function to calculate converting a range of columns to white or black in `O(1)` time, using precalculted column prefix-sums. Let `f(i, type)` represent the minimal cost of the barcode up to the `i`th column, when that column is of type, `type`. Then:

```
f(0, b) ->
  Infinity if x > 1 else C(0, 0, b) 

f(0, w) ->
  Infinity if x > 1 else C(0, 0, w)

f(i, b) ->
  min( C(j, i, b) + f(j - 1, w) )

f(i, w) ->
  min( C(j, i, w) + f(j - 1, b) )

for j = (i - y + 1) to (i - x + 1)
```

(Clearly `f(i)` would be invalid for `i` less than zero, as would be the cost of a range spanning left of the first index.)